# Too much / infinite loop issue - Shopify

Tags: shopify

In Shopify:-
When my for loop code run then this issue occurred:-
"There was a problem loading this website
Try refreshing the page.
If the site still doesn't load, please try again in a few minutes."
console error is
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 ()"

How to fix it.

Comment: Provide more details about the problem you are facing with some example.

Comment: i have created multiple for loop on a page for product filter on basis of tag. When we select a price 0-10 then it will show all products which price is under 0-10 with all collection. 
Reference site: https://www.giftmarket.com.sg/budget.php?b=5&q=7
I have implemented this feature in my shopify store but multiple loop create page loading issue. when i comment this code these line: 
"{% for custom_coll in collections %}
      {% for custom_prod in custom_coll.products %}"
Then page easy to load. How to fix it.

Comment: The reference site is not on Shopify or you just trying to replicate this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your Shopify site has too many collections and products within them so it just fails to load all of them due exceeding memory limits.

I'm assuming that you're trying to replicate the page from the reference URL you provided in your comment. Consider one of the options below to implement the required functionality:

- Create different automated collections for each price range using `Product price` `is less than` condition. This approach is good as it uses Shopify's engine to generate collections, but it still might be quiet tricky to implement grouping as on the ref site you provided in comments.
- Load collections and its products using AJAX requests i.e. request the data only when a customer is scrolling the page down. It will increase page load speed and will slightly decrease the Shopify site load but still is not ideal as data still will be requested on every page load and scrolling down events. You can slightly improve the situation by caching results on the clients' side, but again, is not ideal still.
- Create a custom Shopify application that syncs products with your database. Then you can create an URL on your server that will be used as a data provider for your page. It can be requested via AJAX and return JSON with all the products, grouped by collections and matching the request parameters e.g. `price less than X`.
  You can go further and [add a proxy extension](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/display-data-on-an-online-store-with-an-application-proxy-app-extension) to your app. Shopify proxy would allow you loading a custom page directly from your server with the data from your database and render it within Shopify site like a part of itself. 
  In general, this approach gives you more flexibility on data to output, which can also be cached on your side to increase page speed load drastically.

Personally, I would prefer the last option.